# What's Best way in selecting right model for document comparison

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, pytorch, similarity

We have different pre-trained models like BERT, USE, ELMo, Word2Vec, FastText, etc..,
we have documents in different sizes (large, medium, small). now, we want to do document similarity. how can we decide which pre-trained model/transformer suits for our requirement (for fine-tuning) and what will be the best approach to do?

Comment: What do you mean by "USE"?

Comment: Universal Sentence Encoder (USE)   (https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.11175) @noe

Comment: How long are the documents?

Comment: have edited question, please refer now. @noe

Comment: How many clusters do you want or guess they can be clustered into?

Comment: hope cluster number isn't important here. what will be the thought process/ approach  to select the available pre-trained model for this requirement? @memristor

Comment: The thing is, you want to create a model for a company or to solve a one-time concrete problem?

Answer (score 0):

- I think using transformer's model could be a good choice since it can understand the context well. Also, it can handle any size of data if done correctly.
- About choosing the right model, then there are a lot of pretrained models available on huggingface hub. You can choose any model you want based on your domain and the data that you have.